# Can regex matches in javascript match any word after an equal operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to target `?state=wildcard` in this statement :

```
?state=uncompleted&dancing=yes
```

I would like to target the entire line `?state=uncomplete`, but also allow it to find whatever word would be after the `=` operator. So uncomplete could also be completed, unscheduled, or what have you.

A caveat I am having is granted I could target the wildcard *before* the ampersand, but what if there is no ampersand and the param `state` is by itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```javascript
var regex = /\?state=([^&]+)/;
var match = '?state=uncompleted&dancing=yes'.match(regex);
match; // => ["?state=uncompleted", "uncompleted"]
```

It will match every character after the string "\?state=" except an ampersand, all the way to the end of the string, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative regex: `/\?state=(.+?)(?:&|$)/`

It will match everything up to the first `&` char or the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you don't need regex here. As we all know, regexes tend to be slow, especially when using look aheads. Why not do something like this:

```
var URI = '?state=done&user=ME'.split('&');
var passedVals = [];
```

This gives us ['?state=done','user=ME'], now just do a for loop:

```
for (var i=0;i<URI.length;i++)
{
    passedVals.push(URI[i].split('=')[1]);
}
```

Passed Vals wil contain whatever you need. The added benefit of this is that you can parse a request into an Object:

```
var URI = 'state=done&user=ME'.split('&');
var urlObjects ={};
for (var i=0;i<URI.length;i++)
{
    urlObjects[URI[i].split('=')[0]] = URI[i].split('=')[1];
}
```

I left out the '?' at the start of the string, because a simple .replace('?','') can fix that easily...

Answer (score 1):

You can match as many characters that are not a `&`. If there aren't any `&`s at all, that will of course also work:

```
/(\?state=[^&]+)/.exec("?state=uncompleted");
/(\?state=[^&]+)/.exec("?state=uncompleted&a=1");

// both: ["?state=uncompleted", "?state=uncompleted"]
```